# problem with Post method directly from Java using digikey api oauth 2.0

Tags: java, post, oauth-2.0

I have a code in which I'm requesting the authorization code for Oauth2.0 in digikey api. I created a http handler which handles the response and saves the code and a code that sends the post request to digikey oauth. The problem it is that the post request is having some problems sending itself. I opened a navigator to check the handler and it effectively works using:
 `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(authorizationEndpoint));` but I would prefer to not explicitely open a browser tab. does any one know how to solve this (the code is in java).

Here is the complete code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.sql.Time;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import org.json.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class DigikeyApiConnection {

    private static final String ClientIdDigiKey = "private";
    private static final String ClientSecretDigiKey = "private";
    private static final String TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://api.digikey.com/v1/oauth2/token";
    private static final String Authorization_Endpoint = "https://api.digikey.com/v1/oauth2/authorize";
    private static final String mainEndpoint = "https://api.digikey.com";
    private static final String charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
    private static final String customerId = "private";



    private HttpURLConnection connect(String path) throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLUtils.createSSLContextWithCertificates("C:\\Users\\Felipe Cronenbold\\Desktop\\certificado.crt");
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Set the request method and headers

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        return connection;
    }


    public DigikeyApiConnection() throws Exception {
        getAccesscode();



    }






    public JSONObject getJson(String itemId,HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        String command = "";
        System.out.println(command);
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder response2 = getStringBuilder(connection,inputStream);
        System.out.println(response2);
        return new JSONObject(response2);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            startLocalServer();
            new DigikeyApiConnection();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static StringBuilder getStringBuilder(HttpURLConnection connection, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        return response;
    }

    private void testConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) {
        try {
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println("Connection successful! Status code: " + responseCode);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Connection failed! Status code: " + responseCode);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void getAccesscode() throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection con = connect(Authorization_Endpoint);
        String redirectUri = "http://localhost:8000/getDigikeyCode";
        String request = "response_type=" + URLEncoder.encode("code", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()) +
                "&client_id=" + URLEncoder.encode(ClientIdDigiKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()) +
                "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
        String authorizationEndpoint = Authorization_Endpoint + "?" + request;
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(authorizationEndpoint));
        System.out.println(authorizationEndpoint);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        try (OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream()) {
            output.write(request.getBytes(charset));
        }

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

//        con.setDoOutput(true);
//        writeRequest(con, request);
//        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
        HttpURLConnection redirect = connect(redirectUri);


    }

    private static String getResponse(HttpURLConnection con) throws IOException {
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String responseLine = null;
            while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(responseLine.trim());
            }
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            return response.toString();
        }
    }

    private static class DigikeyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
            // Obtener la cadena de consulta de la URI
            URI uri = exchange.getRequestURI();
            String query = uri.getQuery();

            // Extraer los parámetros de la cadena de consulta
            String code = getQueryParamValue(query, "code");
            String scope = getQueryParamValue(query, "scope");

            // Construir la respuesta en HTML
            String response = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                    "<html lang=\"en\">\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "    <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
                    "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n" +
                    "    <title>Digikey Code Receiver</title>\n" +
                    "</head>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "    <h1>Digikey Code Receiver</h1>\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "    <p>código: " + code + "</p>\n" +
                    "    <p>ambito: " + scope + "</p>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>";

            // Configurar las cabeceras y enviar la respuesta
            exchange.getResponseHeaders().set("Content-Type", "text/html");
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());

            try (OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody()) {
                os.write(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
        }

        // Método auxiliar para extraer el valor de un parámetro de la cadena de consulta
        private String getQueryParamValue(String query, String paramName) {
            String[] params = query.split("&");
            for (String param : params) {
                String[] keyValue = param.split("=");
                if (keyValue.length == 2 && keyValue[0].equals(paramName)) {
                    return keyValue[1];
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
    }

    private static void startLocalServer() throws IOException {
        int port = 8000; // Use the same port as in your redirectUri
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
        server.createContext("/getDigikeyCode", new DigikeyHandler());
        server.start();

        System.out.println("Local Server is running on port " + port);
    }
    private static void writeRequest(HttpURLConnection connection, String request) throws IOException {
        try(OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()){
            output.write(request.getBytes(charset));
        }
    }
}
```